# Merging Extremely large tables

Tags: sql-server

I have seven tables I need to merge.
Each table has three keys and a date.
I have been trying several methods to merge the data, to include just inserting all records into a single table and running a de-duplication T-SQL CTE statement as below given by another member of stack overflow:

```
 ;WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT [key1], [key2], [key3], [date],
           RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [key1], [key2], [key3] ORDER BY isnull([date], '19000101' desc)
        FROM dbo.Table1 t1
        WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                       FROM dbo.Table1 t2 
                       WHERE t1.key1=t2.key1 
                         and t1.key2=t2.key2 
                         and t1.key3=t2.key3 
                         and t1.[date] IS NOT NULL
                     )
    )
    DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

My problem is that each table is 80Mil records strong, resulting in a de-duplication of effort that overloads the SQL Server.

The rules I have is below:

```
CASE 1: before dedupication:            
key1    key2    key3    date
1   A   1   null
1   A   1   null
1   A   1   null

after deduplication:            
key1    key2    key3    date
1   A   1   null
1   A   1   null
1   A   1   null

CASE 2: before dedupication:            
key1    key2    key3    date
1   A   1   1/1/2016
1   A   1   1/1/2016
1   A   1   1/1/2016

after deduplication:            
key1    key2    key3    date
1   A   1   1/1/2016

CASE 3: before dedupication:            
key1    key2    key3    date
1   A   1   1/1/2016
1   A   1   1/2/2016
1   A   1   1/3/2016

after deduplication:            
key1    key2    key3    date
1   A   1   1/3/2016

CASE 4: before deduplication            
1   A   1   1/1/2016
1   A   1   1/1/2016
1   A   1   null

after deduplication:            
key1    key2    key3    date
1   A   1   1/1/2016


CASE 5: before deduplication            
1   A   1   1/1/2016
1   A   1   1/2/2016
1   A   1   null

after deduplication:            
key1    key2    key3    date
1   A   1   1/2/2016
```

As you can see, this is almost a SCD2 scenerio plus the NULL handling issues.

My next attempt is to merge one table into another with de-duplication, then repeat until all are done.

I'm looking at the merge solution, but fail to understand how to work this for that many records.  I am lobbying for SSIS, but to no avail.

I'm looking for any possible idea to perform this task.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your purpose correctly.

Sorry, formatting cannot be kept, or at least I can't.
I suggest you try and past the content in sql server manager.

Considering the data load, I suggest you take into consideration implementing some mid-steps and consolidating relevant data in temporary tables.
If possible, do also consider using the NoLock hint.

- **First step - let's simulate your tables (5, 7 or 10 makes no difference)**

create table #tmp1 (key1 int not null, key2 char(1) not null, key3 int not null, key4 date null)

create table #tmp2 (key1 int not null, key2 char(1) not null, key3 int not null, key4 date null)

create table #tmp3 (key1 int not null, key2 char(1) not null, key3 int not null, key4 date null)

create table #tmp4 (key1 int not null, key2 char(1) not null, key3 int not null, key4 date null)

create table #tmp5 (key1 int not null, key2 char(1) not null, key3 int not null, key4 date null)

insert  #tmp1
values  (1, 'A', 1, null), (1, 'A', 1, null), (1, 'A', 1, null)

insert  #tmp2
values  (1, 'A', 1, '2016-01-01'), (1, 'A', 1, '2016-01-01'), (1, 'A', 1, '2016-01-01')

insert  #tmp3
values  (1, 'A', 1, '2016-01-01'), (1, 'A', 1, '2016-01-02'), (1, 'A', 1, '2016-01-03')

insert  #tmp4
values  (1, 'A', 1, '2016-01-01'), (1, 'A', 1, '2016-01-01'), (1, 'A', 1, null)

insert  #tmp5
values  (1, 'A', 1, '2016-01-01'), (1, 'A', 1, '2016-01-02'), (1, 'A', 1, null)

**- First type of return (I am i doubt about your requirements)

---

select  key1, key2, key3, key4

from    (   select  key1, key2, key3, key4 = max(key4)

```
        from    #tmp1

        where   key4 is not null

        group by key1, key2, key3

        union all

        select  key1, key2, key3, key4 = max(key4)

        from    #tmp2

        where   key4 is not null

        group by key1, key2, key3

        union all

        select  key1, key2, key3, key4 = max(key4)

        from    #tmp3

        where   key4 is not null

        group by key1, key2, key3

        union all

        select  key1, key2, key3, key4 = max(key4)

        from    #tmp4

        where   key4 is not null

        group by key1, key2, key3

        union all

        select  key1, key2, key3, key4 = max(key4)

        from    #tmp5

        where   key4 is not null

        group by key1, key2, key3

        -- nulls, do not deduplicate
        union all
        select  a.key1, a.key2, a.key3, a.key4
        from    #tmp1           a
                left join #tmp1 b on a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2 = b.key2 and a.key3 = b.key3 and b.key4 is not null
        where   a.key4 is null and b.key4 is null
        union all
        select  a.key1, a.key2, a.key3, a.key4
        from    #tmp2           a
                left join #tmp2 b on a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2 = b.key2 and a.key3 = b.key3 and b.key4 is not null
        where   a.key4 is null and b.key4 is null
                    union all
        select  a.key1, a.key2, a.key3, a.key4
        from    #tmp3           a
                left join #tmp3 b on a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2 = b.key2 and a.key3 = b.key3 and b.key4 is not null
        where   a.key4 is null and b.key4 is null
        union all
        select  a.key1, a.key2, a.key3, a.key4
        from    #tmp4           a
                left join #tmp4 b on a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2 = b.key2 and a.key3 = b.key3 and b.key4 is not null
        where   a.key4 is null and b.key4 is null
        union all
        select  a.key1, a.key2, a.key3, a.key4
        from    #tmp5           a
                left join #tmp5 b on a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2 = b.key2 and a.key3 = b.key3 and b.key4 is not null
        where   a.key4 is null and b.key4 is null

    )       a
```

**- Second type of return (I am i doubt about your requirements)

---

select  key1, key2, key3, key4 = max(key4)
from    (   select  key1, key2, key3, key4
            from    #tmp1
            where   key4 is not null
            union all
            select  key1, key2, key3, key4
            from    #tmp2
            where   key4 is not null
            union all
            select  key1, key2, key3, key4
            from    #tmp3
            where   key4 is not null
            union all
            select  key1, key2, key3, key4
            from    #tmp4
            where   key4 is not null
            union all
            select  key1, key2, key3, key4
            from    #tmp5
            where   key4 is not null
        )       nonnulls
group by key1, key2, key3
union all
-- nulls, do not deduplicate
select  a.key1, a.key2, a.key3, a.key4
from    #tmp1           a
        left join #tmp1 b on a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2 = b.key2 and a.key3 = b.key3 and b.key4 is not null
where   a.key4 is null and b.key4 is null
union all
select  a.key1, a.key2, a.key3, a.key4
from    #tmp2           a
        left join #tmp2 b on a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2 = b.key2 and a.key3 = b.key3 and b.key4 is not null
where   a.key4 is null and b.key4 is null
        union all
select  a.key1, a.key2, a.key3, a.key4

from    #tmp3          a
        left join #tmp3 b on a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2 = b.key2 and a.key3 = b.key3 and b.key4 is not null
where   a.key4 is null and b.key4 is null
union all
select  a.key1, a.key2, a.key3, a.key4
from    #tmp4           a
        left join #tmp4 b on a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2 = b.key2 and a.key3 = b.key3 and b.key4 is not null
where   a.key4 is null and b.key4 is null
union all
select  a.key1, a.key2, a.key3, a.key4
from    #tmp5           a
        left join #tmp5 b on a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2 = b.key2 and a.key3 = b.key3 and b.key4 is not null
where   a.key4 is null and b.key4 is null